# Why does CMakeLists file need to be in root of project folder in CLion?

Tags: c++, cmake, clion

It will only build if the `CMakeLists.txt` file is in the project root. Why can't it reside in a `src` subdirectory, for instance? Is there a way to change the settings so it will look there?

Comment: It's normal to put only source files in `/src`. Since `CMakeLists.txt` doesn't get compiled it would go somewhere outside that folder. Idk if CLion can be adjusted in regards to this though.

Comment: @ChrisBeck that makes sense. Is it normal for it to not be in the `src` folder then but in the project root?

Comment: Yeah, for most projects I've seen. Here's an example: https://github.com/llvm-mirror/llvm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's how CMake hierarchy works, since you've created project, you should have root directory (`${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}` variable) where placed you top-level CMake file, with project name and other project scope preferences. In case you want include additional sub directories with source code or sub projects, you should use [add_subdirectory()](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/add_subdirectory.html) function, it will include child CMake file to your project. Your sub directory may be placed only inside your project root directory. Look into [official CMake example](https://cmake.org/examples/) for better understanding.

Answer (score 2):

By default, CLion considers the directory that includes top-level CMakeLists.txt file as a main project directory that includes all the sources. If you want to change it, you need to change CMake project root as written here: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/changing-project-root-directory.html

Comment: I guess they just change variable `${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}` since, **quote**: _"Change Project Root command doesn't affect the actual location of the main CMakeLists.txt file"_ So your top-level CMake will be placed on same place as before, that may confuse other developers who work on your project. And by the way, changing root directory to sub directory of current project take no effect at all. I suggest to not do that.